# Cannot upload image with Intervention image in Laravel 5.2

Tags: php, laravel, file-upload

I am trying to upload an image using the tutorial [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jy2SUxx6uHc). I have followed the instructions exactly as in the video, but once I click on the submit button, it brings me back to the profile page, and the image is unchanged, nothing has changed in the database or uploaded to the folder designated.

Here is my `routes.php`:

```
Route::get('profile', 'UserController@showProfile');
Route::post('profile', 'UserController@updateAvatar');
```

Here is the blade file:

```
<div class="row">
   <div class="col-sm-4">
       <div class="text-align-center">
           <img class="img-circle" src="/uploads/avatars/{{ Auth::user()->avatar }}" alt="64x64" style="height: 112px; border-radius:50%;">
       </div>
       <br>
       <br>
       <div class="text-align-center">
          <form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="{{ url('/profile') }}" method="POST">
          <h5>Update Profile Image</h5>
          <input type="file" name="avatar">
          <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}"> <br>          
          <input type="submit" class="pull-left btn btn-sm btn-primary">
          </form>
       </div>
</div>
```

Here is the controller:

```
 public function showProfile(){

        return view('profile', array('user' => Auth::user()));
    }

    public function updateAvatar(Request $request){
        //Handle the user upload of avatar
        if($request->hasFile('avatar')){
            $avatar = $request->file('avatar');
            $filename = time() . '.' . $avatar->getClientOriginalExtension();
            Image::make($avatar)->resize(200, 200)->save( public_path('/uploads/avatars/' . $filename ) );
            $user = Auth::user();
            $user->avatar = $filename;
            File::
            $user->save();
        }

        return view('profile', array('user' => Auth::user()));
    }
```

I have added a field `avatar` to the `users` table.

Comment: Try debugging by placing a die('QA'); statement inside hasFile. If die() not executed your input doesn't have file. If die() is called, try move_uploaded_file() ---> http://php.net/manual/en/function.move-uploaded-file.php - to see if you can even upload an image

Comment: It executes successfully. with the die statement

Comment: OK... also make sure you have use Image; set for this class

Comment: I did that in the beginning. I think the problem might be with the `$request->file('avatar');` line.

Comment: Then die($avatar->getClientOriginalExtension()) would be wrong...is it?

Comment: No it works. I don't understand what it is, but doesn't laravel provide a functionality of its own through the `Input` facade?

Comment: try $file = Input::file('avatar'); and $file->move($yourPath); instead

Comment: that doesn't work either

Comment: OK..no idea then because I used that code in my image uploading application at my last job

Answer (score 0):

```
public function update_avatar(Request $request){

    // Handle the user upload of avatar
    if($request->hasFile('avatar')){
        $avatar = $request->file('avatar');
        $filename = time() . '.' . $avatar->getClientOriginalExtension();
        $avatar->move('/uploads/avatars', $filename);       
        $user = Auth::user();
        $user->avatar = $filename;
        $user->save();
    }

    return view('profile', array('user' => Auth::user()) );

}
```